# Cannot locate any file inside templates folder from browser

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I've made some thymeleaf templates and want to use it with Spring Boot (on Tomcat) and the only location inside a project where I can find a `.html` file from browser is `src/main/resources/static`. When I place a file there, I can access it with `contextRoot/filename.html`. But when I place it inside `src/main/resources/templates` folder, I cannot access it with neither of this: `root/filename.html, root/resources/filename.html`. What's the problem here?

Comment: Can you please post your code or more clearly specify what you mean by "access"?

Comment: @vphilipnyc There is no code, I just want to "find" those web pages from browser when I place them in the project. By "access" I mean not to get 404 status when I send requests for those pages. I don't know if this is connected to the view resolver, but I guess I should be able to access .html files inside a resources folder somehow by default.

Comment: ok, so in your controller, make sure that you are returning a string like `root/filename`.  You can leave off the extension as Spring Boot will know to resolve it.  This is assuming a folder structure of `src/main/resources/templates/root`.  You can take a look at any example project in the docs or GitHub too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that I didn't have **Spring Boot Thymeleaf Starter** dependency in the POM. I had plain **Thymeleaf** dependency not intended for Spring Boot and using it needed more configuration unlike the first one that works out of the box.